# Create user group using REST API in android

Tags: android, rest, api, xmpp, openfire

I am unable to create user group. I have already tried using roster but get failure to create user group. I have also tried rest api example taking from git hub but getting error "MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class org.igniterealtime.restclient.entity.UserEntity, genericType=class org.igniterealtime.restclient.entity.UserEntity.". I am using "compile('org.igniterealtime:rest-api-client:1.1.3')" to dependencies in gradle. Any suggestion will be appreciated.Here is the code for create user group

```
            RestApiClient restApiClient = new RestApiClient("<serverName>", 9090, authToken);
            UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity("tester9", "Tester9", "test@gmail.com", "12345");

            UserProperty userProperty = new UserProperty();
            userProperty.setKey("Content-Type");
            userProperty.setValue("application/xml");
            List<UserProperty> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(userProperty);
            userEntity.setProperties(list);
            GroupEntity groupEntity = new GroupEntity();
            groupEntity.setName("Test");
            restApiClient.createUser(userEntity);
            restApiClient.createGroup(groupEntity);
```

Logcat :

```
I/LoggingFilter: 1 * Sending client request on thread AsyncTask #3
                 1 > POST https://90.0.0.166:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users
                 1 > Authorization: aPQ1n9khu384OUri
                 1 > Content-Type: application/xml
E/iterInterceptorExecutor: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class org.igniterealtime.restclient.entity.UserEntity, genericType=class org.igniterealtime.restclient.entity.UserEntity.
E/ClientRequest: Error while committing the request output stream.
                 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
                     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:396)
                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:103)
                     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143)
                     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
                     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
                     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
                     at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector$4.getOutputStream(HttpUrlConnector.java:385)
                     at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:200)
                     at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commitStream(CommittingOutputStream.java:194)
                     at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commit(CommittingOutputStream.java:262)
                     at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundMessageContext.commitStream(OutboundMessageContext.java:816)
                     at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:545)
                     at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:388)
                     at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
                     at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:255)
                     at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:700)
                     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
                     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
                     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
                     at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
                     at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:696)
                     at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:448)
                     at org.igniterealtime.restclient.RestClient.call(RestClient.java:145)
                     at org.igniterealtime.restclient.RestClient.post(RestClient.java:91)
                     at org.igniterealtime.restclient.RestApiClient.createUser(RestApiClient.java:92)
                     at com.marothiatechs.mchat.LoginActivity$CreateNewAccount.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:456)
                     at com.marothiatechs.mchat.LoginActivity$CreateNewAccount.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:389)
                     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                    Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
                        ... 40 more
                        Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed
                            ... 40 more
                        Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xaabbbb40: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
                 error:100bd10c:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER (external/boringssl/src/ssl/s3_pkt.c:311 0xab4bbd97:0x00000000)
                     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
                            at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImp
```

UserEntity.class

```
package org.igniterealtime.restclient.entity;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

/**
 * The Class UserEntity.
 */
@XmlRootElement(name = "user")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "username", "name", "email", "password", "properties" })
public class UserEntity {

    /** The username. */
    private String username;

    /** The name. */
    private String name;

    /** The email. */
    private String email;

    /** The password. */
    private String password;

    /** The properties. */
    private List<UserProperty> properties;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new user entity.
     */
    public UserEntity() {

    }

    /**
     * Instantiates a new user entity.
     *
     * @param username            the username
     * @param name            the name
     * @param email            the email
     * @param password the password
     */
    public UserEntity(String username, String name, String email, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the username.
     *
     * @return the username
     */
    @XmlElement
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the username.
     *
     * @param username
     *            the new username
     */
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the name.
     *
     * @return the name
     */
    @XmlElement
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the name.
     *
     * @param name
     *            the new name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the email.
     *
     * @return the email
     */
    @XmlElement
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the email.
     *
     * @param email
     *            the new email
     */
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the password.
     *
     * @return the password
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the password.
     *
     * @param password
     *            the new password
     */
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the properties.
     *
     * @return the properties
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "property")
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "properties")
    public List<UserProperty> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the properties.
     *
     * @param properties
     *            the new properties
     */
    public void setProperties(List<UserProperty> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }
}
```

Comment: show ur log cat

Comment: Hello Roy, is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: Post ur User entity class

Comment: @suvendhu pradhan  plz post ur class

Comment: @Roy pls help to resolve this issue.

Comment: This means the server is using a different security mechanism

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your exception is logged by the framework as well as thrown to your client code. It may be either impossible to suppress it, or (if it is logged via a logging API) you could control it with an appropriate logging level configuration.